# multiple array table in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

**Currently I have written code for calculating sum of input on my input

for One Table**

```
$('#example122').on('input', '.calculate', function () {
    calculateTotal();
});
function calculateTotal() 
{
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $('#example122 tbody tr').each(function() {

        var c_sbt = $('.calculate', this).val();
                      grandTotal += parseFloat(c_sbt);
                      });

    // VAT, DISCOUNT, SHIPPING, TOTAL, SUBTOTAL:
    var subT = parseFloat(grandTotal);


    $('.sub_total').val(subT.toFixed(2));
}
```

**But now i want code for multiple table having same ID **

```
$('table').foreach(on('input', '.calculate', function () {
    calculateTotal();
}));
function calculateTotal() 
{
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $('table tbody tr').each(function() {

        var c_sbt = $('.calculate', this).val();
                      grandTotal += parseFloat(c_sbt);
                      });

    // VAT, DISCOUNT, SHIPPING, TOTAL, SUBTOTAL:
    var subT = parseFloat(grandTotal);


    $('.sub_total').val(subT.toFixed(2));
}
```

**  this code is not working **

HTML CODE

my table data is a input type="text" i want to calculate when user changes the value

```
            <td style="padding-top:15px;" align="right"><b>TOTAL SALARY</b>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="sub_total" id="sub_total"  class="form-control sub_total" autocomplete="off" class="form-group"  ></td>
            </tfoot>
```

Comment: Look at how you iterate over your `tr` when it's working and compare it to when you iterate over `table`. (Hint: `each` vs. `foreach`).

Comment: Please provide the html structure that is helpful.

Comment: I have added html code

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know when you don't have the HTML in your post but I think that your main issue is that you're using the keyword `foreach` when you try to iterate over your tables. As you can se when you iterate over your rows you use `each`.

Below is a snippet that does something in line with what it looks like you're after. That is, it iterates over multiple tables and adds the values for each column on each row in each table up.

This is probably not exactly what you're trying to do but might point you in the right direction.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').each(function() {
    calculateTotal(this);
  });
})

function calculateTotal(table) {
  var grandTotal = parseFloat($('.sub_total').text());

  $(table).find('tbody tr').each(function() {
    var c_sbt = $(this).text();
    grandTotal += parseFloat(c_sbt);
  });

  var subT = parseFloat(grandTotal);

  $('.sub_total').html(subT.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="this">10.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="this">12.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="this">10.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="this">10.22</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p class="sub_total">0</p>
```

Comment: So given the code snippet above, does that help you? Do you see anything that differs from your original code and how you could improve it? My example iterates when the page is loaded  but it seems like you know how to call a function on a click event. Have you tried that?

Comment: i want to implement function similar on('input', '.calculate', function () { like this with each loop  or keyup function  then only it is helpful in my code